# pass ng-template content from parent component but i dont want ro render it

Tags: angular

I have 3 components, component A is responsive to render UI with ngTemplateOutlet, and component B is inserting ng-template to component A with content projection so that component A can render it, but I don't want component B to insert ng-template directly, I want component B to get ng-template content from another component (here component C), and then component A render it, how can do that?

component B example:

```
<p-pickList>
  <ng-template #item>
    ///some codes
  </ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

component A is p-pickList and is a Library.

component c template example:

```
<componet-b>
  <ng-template>
    //some codes that I want eventually produced go here
  <ng-template>
</componet-b>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a'
  template: `
    <ng-content>
    </ng-content>
  `
})
export class ComponentA {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-b'
  template: `
    <div>
      <app-component-a>
        <ng-container
          *ngIf="someService.componentCTemplateRef"
          [ngTemplateOutlet]="someService.componentCTemplateRef">
        </ng-container>
      </app-component-a>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ComponentB {

  constructor(public someService: SomeService) {}

}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-c'
  template: `
    <ng-template #TemplateToInject>
      <div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

    <div #OtherCode>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ComponentC implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('TemplateToInject', { static: true }) templateToInject: TemplateRef<any>

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someService.componentCTemplateRef = this.templateToInject
  }

}
```

*Note: you can also pass the templateToInject directly from ComponentC to ComponentB via @Input() if you have a parent-child relationship, but the service approach is more flexible*

Comment: thank you for the answer, but component B must not render the template(because you used ng-container with ngTemplateOutlet) so this doesn't work